# Why can't a UID 0 process hardlink to SUID files in a user namespace?

Tags: linux, hard-link, capabilities, userns

Consider the following transcript of a user-namespaced shell running with root privileges (UID 0 within the namespace, unprivileged outside):

```
# cat /proc/$$/status | grep CapEff
CapEff: 0000003cfdfeffff
# ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root   4096 Sep 16 22:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root   4096 Sep 16 22:08 ..
-rwSr--r--  1 nobody nobody    0 Sep 16 22:09 file
# ln file link
ln: failed to create hard link 'link' => 'file': Operation not permitted
# su nobody -s /bin/bash -c "ln file link"
# ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  2 root   root   4096 Sep 16 22:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root   4096 Sep 16 22:08 ..
-rwSr--r--  2 nobody nobody    0 Sep 16 22:09 file
-rwSr--r--  2 nobody nobody    0 Sep 16 22:09 link
```

Apparently the process has the CAP_FOWNER permission (0x8) and thus should be able to hardlink to arbitrary files. However, it failes to link the SUID'd test file owned by `nobody`. There is nothing preventing the process from switching to `nobody` and then linking the file, thus the parent namespace does not seem to be the issue.

**Why can't the namespaced UID 0 process hardlink `link` to `file` without switching its UID?**

Comment: As I'm unsure about GPL compatibility of CC-BY-SA, I did not include any kernel sources in the question; I assumed FOWNER should be sufficient from looking at `fs/namei.c`, the check in `static int may_linkat` should succeed if `capable(CAP_FOWNER)` is true.

Comment: Adding a link to https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/namei.c?id=refs/tags/v4.2.4#n977 should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior described in the question was a bug, which has been [fixed in the upcoming Linux 4.4](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f2ca379642d7a843be972ea4167abdd3c8c9e5d1).